# How can I migrate svn to a new system , without root access to system

Tags: svn

I want to migrate an svn repository in one server to another. I dont have access to that server, but I have svn access with all permissions. Can I replicate the entire svn repository in another server of mine.?

I cant access the server because it is a hosted svn provided by Assembla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they have subversion 1.7, there is new tool added in 1.7 for remote dumps called svnrdump.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html