# Subversion - make a copy of the entire repository

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

I am using a commercial Subversion hosting service. In order to make a copy of the entire repository, I can make a request.  This gets put into a queue, which normally takes hours.  In addition, I have several (10s of) projects hosted there.  Each copy request has to be separately for each project, which is kind of painful if I want to do this on a regular basis.

So, is there a way I can make an exact copy of the archive from a Linux command line?  i.e., just with the SVN client installed?

Or is there any easy (preferably scriptable) way to obtain an archive copy of my repositories?

Kind Regards,
Madeleine.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452626/how-can-i-migrate-svn-to-a-new-system-without-root-access-to-system/11452935#11452935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Subversion version 1.7 or later, there is the command:  svnrdump  which worked for me.

Syntax:

```
svnrdump dump https://yourRepository/yourProject > yourProject.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the tool [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net). It looks like it'll do what you want.

Comment: Interesting, there is svnrdump and rsvndump.

Comment: @MadeleineP.Vincent I think svnrdump is new with SVN 1.7. The rsvndump is a separate project.